# How Make WebPage thumbnail on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, screenshot, thumbnails

I'm using Django / Python. After saving the model I want to make a screenshot (preview) of how it looks in the template and save it on model field. Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you actually want it to work. You can however use the following links to pass a url and fetch its screenshot:

http://www.websnapr.com/

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/shotbot

These are the third party applications which work just fine. You can try them.

Answer (score 3):

in GAE you have limited access to external resource

outside GAE you can use webkit2png http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/